# Trying to style Woocommerce sidebar Cart Widget

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css, widgets, sidebar

I have looked at length to find CSS that will change the background color, border radius and product info text color. I think this may not be a "mini cart". The price of the item, subtotal and View Cart / Checkout buttons follow the styling Ive done to the cart. I have successfully changed my product text color on my actual Cart page. So frustrating! Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to use your browser's debug tools to 'inspect' the individual parts of the widget: it should show you what CSS it is using to style it, and which files it comes from.

Comment: Thanks, I remembered about that Inspect idea. I was able to style the background color and border radius. But I cant figure out how to style the text that identifies the product. Its still the default blue.

Comment: Could you share the link to the site you're working on?

Comment: the site is pancakehollowsugarworks.com

Comment: For the sidebar cart widget to come up you must add something to your cart.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, this code allowed me to change the Product description color on the Cart sidebar widget.

.widget ul li a {
color: #680000;
}